# NextJs SSG Firebase deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

**TL;DR**

The data added after building the project is not shown anywhere. It is in the DB but not showing on the site.

So I made a site for meetups while using firebase as a DB. Everything is working correctly in the dev mode. Even when I build my project and export it using `next build && next export` and then run it using `next start`, it works completely fine. But when I run the `firebase deploy --only hosting` command, all the new data that I added while running the project locally isn't there. It is present in the DB though.

What I want to ask is that does firebase not support SSG ??

I did some research and found that the deployment on Vercel is running perfectly.

Below is my code for the `index.js` file

```
function HomePage(props) {
  console.log("Number of meetups: " + props.meetups.length);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>Next Js Meetups</title>
        <meta name="Description" content="Browse a huge list of Meetups" />
      </Head>
      <MeetupList meetups={props.meetups}></MeetupList>
    </Fragment>
  );
}


export async function getStaticProps() {
  // Fetch data from API
  console.log("Getting data in getStaticProps");
  var list = await GetAllMeetups();

  return {
    props: {
      meetups: list,
    },
    revalidate: 5,
  };
}

export default HomePage;
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Incremental Static Regeneration is not supported by `next export`. See [Static HTML Export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features).

Answer (score 0):

That is because `getStaticProps` fetches data **only** when you run `next build && next export`. It doesn't fetch each time the page is loaded, only during build time. The drawback of SSG is that once the data changes you have to rebuild and redeploy your project.

If you want it to update each time, use SSR & `getServerSideProps`, but you will not be able to deploy it on Firebase as it only supports SSG. For the deployment of a server side rendering Next.js app, I can personally recommend Netlify.

Comment: But as I mentioned above the newly added data is getting fetched when I run the project locally. And the tutorial that I am following is using Vercel to deploy but the data is also getting fetched in that [tutorial](https://youtu.be/MFuwkrseXVE?t=11220).

Comment: But is it not because you are rebuilding the project before the deploy? As I mentioned before, `getStaticProps` only runs **on build**.

Comment: Right... So what do you suggest should I use SSR or do I still have any other option ??

Comment: You can still use SSG for this purpose but instead of fetching the data in `getStaticProps`, run the fetch in `useEffect` once the component loads using `fetch` or `axios`. This of course will add some delay, because it will get fetched **after the page has loaded**. You can use SSR to have the data there the moment the page loads, but you won't be able to use Firebase hosting to deploy.

Comment: Okay. Great thanks for taking the time to explain it to me.

Comment: Also can you please explain to me then what the point of revalidate is? I mean isn't it there to rebuild the page after the specified time

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the revalidate property on your `getStaticProps`. Incremental static regeneration (ISR) is a new feature of Next.js I haven't yet worked with but from what I know it is basically static generation but on a per-page basis, rebuilding the specified next page at runtime if the data's out of date and resolving to static HTML. I can now see why it worked on Vercel, but not on Firebase as Firebase only supports SSG.

Answer (score 0):

Hi folks I ran into this question doing some light reading on NextJs

Firebase now supports SSR